# How to change order of x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reverse the order of my x-axis(specificities) so that my data starts from 1 instead of 0. Any advice on this?

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=specificities, y=sensitivities)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use `scale_x_reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve your task:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=specificities, y=sensitivities)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse(limits = c(1,0))
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(sensitivities = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9897959, 
0.9693878, 0.9540816, 0.9540816, 0.9438776, 0.9336735, 0.9081633, 
0.877551, 0.877551, 0.877551, 0.877551, 0.877551, 0.877551, 0.872449, 
0.872449, 0.8622449), specificities = c(0, 0.01020408, 0.04081633, 
0.12244898, 0.25, 0.32142857, 0.37244898, 0.43367347, 0.4744898, 
0.5255102, 0.59183673, 0.67346939, 0.7755102, 0.82142857, 0.87244898, 
0.88265306, 0.89285714, 0.89795918, 0.90306122, 0.92346939, 0.93367347, 
0.93367347)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```